# how to get window's position when the window is moving in xlib / xcb

Tags: c++, ubuntu, xcb

on Ubuntu 18.04 KDE desktop, I can not get exactly window's position when window is moving.

Using  xcb_get_geomerty() function, I can get window's position.

But when window is moving, the position of window is still the same as before,there is no change. When released mouse and completed window movement, then I can get exactly window's position.

```
    auto geom = xcb_get_geometry(xcb_connection(), window);
    auto offset = xcb_translate_coordinate(xcb_connection(), window, rootwin, geom->x, geom->y);

    offset->dst_x // top-level window's x offset on the screen
    offset->dst_y // top-level window's y offset on the screen
    geom->width   // top-level window's width
    geom->height  // top-level window's height
```

Get the window's position correctly when window moving in other desktop enviroment(ie. gnome, xfce) but KDE. Is there any other way or xwindow property can get window's position when moving?